# Unity obj file rendering black

Tags: unity-game-engine, wavefront

Using diffuse shader with Main color and no Base RGB
[image: Using diffuse shader with Main color and no Base RGB]

Using diffuse shader with Base RGB
[image: Using diffuse shader with Base RGB]

I checked the UV maps and all of them have a value between 0-1 in the obj file.

I have added the obj file and the texture file here 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B671EegruC4WV2tSa283aXB4Z0k?usp=sharing

Comment: Your model is not UV mapped. Uv mapping a face is really complicated. It takes good texturing skills to accomplish that. You have to use another 3D program such as Maya to do the UV mapping with that image you provided. There are many tutorials out there but this question does not belong here.

Comment: As per my understanding lines with vt are texture coordinates and the line(s) with f specify faces that are a part of the UV map

What else am I missing the obj file?

Comment: Just find an artist to texture that for you if you are programmer. If you want to become an artist there are many **video** tutorials out there. There is no way you can learn that from comment section. I checked this file with Maya and my first comment is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Checked in blender you don't have correct UV mapping for the image and mesh that you want to use which is causing the wrong pixels(black) of image getting displayed -
[image: UV map screenshot]